# Bad encoding import SQL file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, encoding, utf-8, converters

I would like import a SQL file encoded into Latin1. I would like keep this file encoding. Data into sql file are well encoded into Latin1.

I executed this command :

`mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p Database --default-character-set=latin1 < file.sql`

But data are encoded into utf8 encoded into Database. I don't understand why data are converted. I should obtain "Ã©" (Latin1)and I obtain "é" (utf8).

I created my Database with :

`CREATE DATABASE Database CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;`

Can you help me please, how I can import my SQL file to keep enconding ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database charset may be overridden by the table charset.  The table charset may be overridden by the column charset.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

What encoding are the bytes in `file.sql`?  If the *character* `é` takes one *byte* (hex `E9`), then it is encoded latin1.  If it takes two *bytes* (hex `C3A9`), then it is utf8.  If `C3A9` is *interpreted* as latin`, it comes out as`Ã©`.  This is called Mojibake.

By saying `--default-character-set=latin1`, you are announcing that the bytes in the source are encoded latin1.

Even if the source bytes are latin1 (eg hex 96), the column in the table can be `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  The encoding will be converted (to C3A9) as the insertion is performed.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
mysql -u your-username -p your-password --database your-db --default-character-set utf8mb4 < my_data.sql
```

worked.

Encoding is still hell on earth, don't get why MySql/Maria are still not defaulted to UTF-8 and even ignoring the file's import format.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 defaults to utf8mb4.  This has led to a significant decline on charset questions in this forum.  Unfortunately, there are still datasets outside MySQL that are in other encodings.